# jQuery Autocomplete (UI) - Problems with web service accepting GET requests

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

How do I get my web service to accept GET requests?  Basically, I can make JSON requests which the older autoComplete plugin's would make to a web service without issue.  Now, using the newer Autocomplete (either jQuery UI or DevBridge) now sends a:

```
$.Get(paramaters)
```

Which makes a call as URL?paramters=value.

I get the error "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in Web Method()"

Researching this has lead me to believe it is because by default ASP.NET 1.1 and up, disables HTTPGET/POST by default and that you have to open it up with the MSDN workaround:

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

But this causing me to get errors that it is trying to serialize an interface which is not allowed on another class.

So how do I allow my web service to accept a call using the URL?paramater=value? and return a json object?

Answer (score 0):

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: This didn't do anything.  Is it possible that it would be affected if either:  A) I am running .NET 2 or B) I have the attrib [ScriptService] on the class?

Comment: script service on the class is not not the problem. problem is asp.net version!!